# Receiving value error unable to get authority configuration for domain name

Tags: azure, authentication, authority

I'm getting a value error when configuring the authority using the domain name when I created my web app following the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=macos

ValueError: Unable to get authority configuration for https://webprojectdomain.b2clogin.com/webprojectdomain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_profile_editing. Authority would typically be in a format of https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant Also please double check your tenant name or GUID is correct.

I changed the domain name, checked the secret and client ID was correct.